# How to add more than 3 numbers in a contact in android programatically

Tags: android, android-contacts

I need to modify the contacts App contacts from my application. I am using the following way:

```
private void UpdateInsertContact()
    {

        Intent intentInsertEdit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
        intentInsertEdit.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        // Add code here to insert extended data, if desired
        intentInsertEdit.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "7547874590");
        intentInsertEdit.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, contactName);
        intentInsertEdit.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE, "7547874590");
        intentInsertEdit.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE, "7547874590");

        // Sends the Intent with an request ID
        startActivity(intentInsertEdit);
    }
```

But this way i am able to add only 3 contacts. How do i add more than 3 conatcts.

Answer (score 4):

yes you can add more than three contacts using Intent . but you have to use contentValues and add it to the ArrayList and pass it as an Extra through the intent, as shown below

```
Intent intentInsertEdit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
intentInsertEdit.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
intentInsertEdit.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, contactName);
ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

//Filling data with phone numbers
ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
row.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row.put(Phone.NUMBER, "97");
row.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
data.add(row);

ContentValues row2 = new ContentValues();
row2.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row2.put(Phone.NUMBER, "9746");
row2.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
data.add(row2);

ContentValues row3 = new ContentValues();
row3.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row3.put(Phone.NUMBER, "974611");
row3.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME);
data.add(row3);


ContentValues row4 = new ContentValues();
row4.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row4.put(Phone.NUMBER, "97461180");
row4.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_OTHER);
data.add(row4);
intentInsertEdit.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
startActivity(intentInsertEdit);
```

this way you can add multiple numbers in the same contact, hope this answers your question :)